# How do I convert a list of lists to dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a list of boxes(unique, with id) and in each box there are certain items(unique, with id). 
Example:

```
list<box> boxes = new list<boxes>;
```

where,

```
class box
{   ...
    list<item> items = new list<item>;
    ...
}
```

- Box1: item1, item2, ...
- Box2: item4, item5, ...
- Box3: ...

I need to find the item details, given the item id. For this I current do something like this:

```
foreach (box b in boxes)
{
    foreach (item i in b.items)
    {
        if (i.id == searchId)
            return i;
    }
}
```

Question is: How can I convert this list data structure to a dictionary data structure?

As I have keys (Id), so I think using a dictionary would be a better choice?

Comment: You are looking for box, or for item in box? If you are looking for box, then inner loop makes no sense. If you are looking for item, then why you are providing box id to search?

Comment: I'm sorry, edited my return statement. I'm looking for the item in the box

Comment: @dev_wired but you are looking by box id?

Comment: Your loops can be translated to: `Loop through all the boxes until reaching a box which has items and whose Id matches the searchId, then return the first item of that box and stop looping.` Are you sure this is what you're intending? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: The loop looks in each box, for each item and returns back the item which matches the searchID. All the items are unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's possible that same items can exist in several boxes, you can select all items, and group them by id, then select first item from each group as a value for dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, item> items = boxes.SelectMany(b => b.items)
                                   .GroupBy(i => i.id)
                                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g.First());
```

If all items have unique ids:

```
var items = boxes.SelectMany(b => b.items)                     .
                 .ToDictionary(i => i.id);
```

---

Getting item will look like:

```
if (items.ContainsKey(searchId))
    return items[searchId];
```

As @Douglas stated, to avoid double lookup it's better to use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
item i;
if (items.TryGetValue(searchId, out i))
    return i;
```

NOTE: Linq alternative without dictionary will be (it does exactly same as your code - enumerates boxes and their items for each search):

```
var item = boxes.SelectMany(b => b.items).FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == searchId);
```

So, if you don't want to hold dictionary with items between searches, or if you need to execute single search, then you can use this solution.

Comment: +1: However, you should use `TryGetValue` to avoid the double lookup cost.

Comment: @Douglas thanks, and agree, TryGetValue will be better

Comment: Thanks for giving both cases! However, in my case all items are unique. This will seem to do the trick.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy : which option will provide faster search results? The LINQ method or the dictionary's TryGetValue? Supposing I am calling this search code 1000 times...

Comment: @dev_wired definitely dictionary will be faster if you need lookup values several times. If you are searching items in same list of boxes 1000 times, than creating dictionary will be much faster (but it will use some memory to hold items)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your items are unique:

```
var dictionary = boxes.SelectMany(box => box.items).ToDictionary(item => item.id);
```

You can then look up values using:

```
item i;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(searchID, out i))
    return i;
```